# Partial functions: how should I normalize the output type of two partials?

Tags: python, functional-programming, partials

I'm having trouble with this one... I have some code uses `functools.partial`, so that I can pass no-parameter functions to subsequent functions.  All the examples that I have are from `random` and return integers, such as:

```
def main():
    random.seed()
    adist = functools.partial(random.uniform, 20, 2000) # no parameter function that returns int
    tdist = functools.partial(random.randrange, 4096) # no parameter function returning int
```

These are then used later in a constructor that looks something like this:

```
for n in range(4):
    random.seed()
    env = simpy.Environment()  # Create the SimPy environment
    line = runSim(env, adist, sdist, tdist) # dists expected to be ints
```

And each time runSim is executed, we get different random values based on the distributions described in the `partial` definition.  What I want to do next is just define another distribution partial function, but this one is using`random.choices()`, which returns a *list* rather than an *integer* -- if we strictly do this, it makes this version incompatible with the rest of the code, which expects a numeric type)

```
sdist = functools.partial(random.choices, population=[64, 536, 1300, 1500], weights=[0.4, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2])
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to build or modify the partial function such that it ALSO returns an integer.  I can't directly subscript the callable, even though it returns a list.  I think there may be some way to combine partials (nest partials?  partial partials?) but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: This is where function composition operator like `∘` would come in handy: `sdist = itemgetter(0) ∘ partial(random.choices, ...)`. You can write this more verbosely with a `lambda` expression: `sdist = lambda : itemgetter(0)(random.choices(...))`.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is known as [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)), one way to achieve this in Python is the following:

```
import functools
import random

from operator import itemgetter

random.seed(42)


def compose(f, g):
    def composition():
        return f(g())

    return composition


sdist = functools.partial(random.choices, population=[64, 536, 1300, 1500], weights=[0.4, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2])

new_sdist = compose(itemgetter(0), sdist)

print(new_sdist())
```

**Output**

```
536
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `partial`, just write a wrapper function that takes no parameters and returns the desired value, in the desired form:

```
def sdist():
    return random.choices(population=[64, 536, 1300, 1500], weights=[0.4, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2])[0]
```

If you want to keep thins in one line, just use the lambda keyword:

```
sdist = lambda: random.choices(population=[64, 536, 1300, 1500], weights=[0.4, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2])[0]
```

From your text and comments, it seens you are exploring partial, and determined to continue on it: partial is readable, and to a certain extent, guaranteed to cover all corner cases, and maybe expose something on the metadata of the function-to-be-called, but it is no much different than simply wrapping the original function in another call - like one can do with:

```
def partial(func, *args, **kw):
    def partial_callable(*more_args, **more_kw):
        final_args = args + more_args
        final_kw = kw.copy()
        final_kw.update(more_kw)
        return func(*final_args, **final_kw)
    return partial_callable
```

In other words: partial is a subset of what is possible to do by wrapping your callable in another callable with your desired signature. And the part that is limited in partial is exactly that, while it allows you to bind input parameters and fully customize the wanted-arguments, it returns the raw value of the wrapped function.

If you want to keep your code with the same look, then you might just define a "super-partial" that will take in, as second positional parameter, another callable which will transform the return value for the main function. (I don't recommend it to be a named parameter, as it could conflict with a named parameter in the callable):

```
def partial_normalize(func, normalizer, /, *args, **kw):
    def partial_callable(*more_args, **more_kw):
        final_args = args + more_args
        final_kw = kw.copy()
        final_kw.update(more_kw)
        result = func(*final_args, **final_kw)
        return normalizer(result) if normalizer else result
    return partial_callable
```

And now you can do:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sdist = partial_normalize(random.choices, itemgetter(0), population=[64, 536, 1300, 1500], weights=[0.4, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2])
```

(`operator.itemgetter(N)` returns a callable that will retrieve the Nth item (equivalent to the `mylist[N]` syntax) of the parameter passed to it)

(the `/` in the parameter list is a Python 3.8 new synatax that indicates the first 2 parameters must be positional, and free the names `func` and `normalizer` to be used as keyword-arguments on the wrapped function. For Python versions up to 3.7 just omit it)

Comment: I had used your first example somewhere else, but was as much trying to understand the partial usage rather than "just" solving the problem. If this is one of those things where the most pythonic way to do is with the wrapper, that would make sense... it just seemed that the partial infrastructure would make more sense here.

Comment: I wrote a second part to the answer that I hope explains better what `partial` does and  will clarify why I am saying you can just wrap the callable in a lambda (along with a fancier partial if you want to keep things generic)